# Create subfolder under different named folders

Tags: windows, batch-file

Can anybody tell me how to do the following in in a DOS batch script? (*.bat):

•Create a folder only under different folders on remote machines

In more detail, I want to create a **folder named TMP** on the

COMPUTER1/D/market1/TMP
COMPUTER1/D/market2/TMP
COMPUTER2/D/market1/TMP
COMPUTER2/D/market2/TMP

I can do a FOR loop to run the batch on different computer but I need to create this TMP directory under a diferent folder ie market1 market2 market3 market4 and so on

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then just add a variable counter to your for loop and call your batch script with argument...:

```
script.bat 2
```

And in batch script then retrieve the argument....

```
mkdir  market%1
```

**EDIT:**
when I look at your comment it looks like you are doing it in one script then you want to use something like:

first.bat:

```
    set count=1
    set hostname=computer
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    FOR /F %%C IN (%FILENAME%) DO ( files\psexec -c 
                                    mkdir "D:\Program Files\work\!hostname!-!count!\tmp" /s /q
                                    if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
                                        exit /b !ERRORLEVEL!
                                    )
                                    echo Starting %%C 
                        set /a count=!count!+1
        )
```

Comment: FOR /F %%C IN (%FILENAME%) DO (
 mkdir  market%1

echo Starting %%C

Comment: mkdir "D:\%%market-%1\tmp" market is a folder name and is also the hostname followed by the dash and a number. Our tmp will be under that folder. Simple mkdir return with error code 0. Can you please help

Comment: if it is not working can you put your code here so I can make a look at it... because maybe I do not understand what are you asking for... but that script what I posted is working for me... it creates market_1 to market_n dirs...

Comment: I have now split it up in 2 batch. Number 1 has a loop command FOR /F %%C IN (%FILENAME%) DO (

files\psexec -c abc.bat \\%%C


echo Starting %%C  


)

Comment: where as abc.bat contains mkdir "D:\Program Files\work\%hostname%-!count!\tmp" /s /q  
set /a count=!count!+1

Comment: the folder name work directory is the hostname followed by a dash and then a number starting from 1 to 24. So basically tmp to be created under 24 folders.

Comment: mkdir "D:\Program Files\work\%computername%-1/tmp works but is there anyway to stop the script if \%computername%-35 does not exist

Answer (score 0):

This may help you: it will create `market1\TMP` to `market255\TMP` on the two computers.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (computer1 computer2) do (
   for /L %%b in (1,1,255) do (
      md "\\%%a\D\market%%b\TMP"
   )
)
```